# VB5 "global" error handling

Tags: error-handling, vb6

We have to handle very old code, written in VB5 that should run without user interfering.

Most of the subs and functions handles it's error using "on error goto...resume" statement, but some of it doesn't.  We must avoid modal messages in any case.

Is there any way to create global error handling or avoid the message box of "runtime error..." and simply close process on unhandled error? (I can re-run it if needed when stopped, but can't click the "enter" or mouse).

Tnx, Guy.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to abort the procedure when an error is raised you can use a style like this

```
Begin Sub Blah()

On Error goto errplace

'procedure code here

Exit Sub
errplace:
End sub
```

You can use [MZ tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/download.aspx) add on to add error handling code to any sub/function in VB6 with a single click on its toolbar (not sure about vb5 though)

Comment: Most of the functions already has error trapping (more or minus what you show in your answer), but I'm looking for something that I want have to add every sub separately, and can't use automation for it because that the code already has something that does more or less this job and I do not want to override it.

Comment: Errors bubble up until an error handler is found or none are found. So an error handler in Sub Main may do it.